# Property name and value for a object

Tags: c#, reflection

I want to print all the object paramters and their values, but exceptions are raised with below code, can you please let me know where i am going wrong

```
     foreach (PropertyInfo prop in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
     {
        Console.WriteLine(prop.Name + " := " + prop.GetValues(obj.Name, null));
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's important to remember that reflection info is metadata about the type. You can retrieve info about the type without an instance, but an *instance* of the type is needed to retrieve instance data.

For example:

```
var instance = new Foo();

// no instance needed to get metadata
var propInfos = typeof( Foo ).GetProperties();

foreach( PropertyInfo prop in propInfos )
{
    // instance needed to get an instance value
    Console.WriteLine( prop.Name + " := " + prop.GetValue( instance ) );
}
```

The first argument of `GetValue()` is "The object whose property value will be returned."

[Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b05d59ty%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

`GetValue` of `PropertyInfo` required **object** and index, not `object.Name`,
 this code must work in this case:

```
foreach (PropertyInfo prop in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
{
   Console.WriteLine(prop.Name + " := " + prop.GetValue(obj, null));
}
```